# how I can use container for Footer?

Tags: flutter

Hello everyone this is my Header how I can use it for Footer?

```dart
Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 8,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.green[500],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(20))),
```

I'm trying with Colum

```dart
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end
```

and Row

```dart
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you include full sample scaffold. Also scaffold has some property like bottomNavigationBar

Comment: I do it thanks to you

Comment: my answer was deleted by mistake which u ranked..can u ranked it again

Comment: + You can add image that you are trying to archive

Answer (score 0):

failing to understand ur question but if u mean to place this container at bottom of screen
here is the code

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      children: [
        Container(
          width: MediaQuery
              .of(context)
              .size
              .width,
          height: MediaQuery
              .of(context)
              .size
              .height / 8,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.green[500],
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(20))),

        ),
      ],);
  }
}
```

Comment: it was deleted by mistake